# Piping PDF to Express Response results in blank PDF

Tags: javascript, express, pdf, character-encoding, pdfkit

I'm trying to create a PDF in a Lambda function and I am having trouble using the `.pipe()` function from PDF Kit. When opening the downloaded PDF, it is blank. I have had success by converting the PDF to a base64 string and opening that, but this won't be feasible when the PDF size & # of requests increase.

My ideal approach is to use `.pipe()` as I've seen in multiple guides. This is the code below that is returning a blank PDF. I have tried using both `responseType: 'blob'`  and `responseType: arraybuffer` on my client. Both open blank files.

```
let pdf = new PDFDocument();
pdf.text("hello world", 50, 50);

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
res.setHeader(
  "Content-Disposition",
  `attachment; filename=test.pdf`
);
res.status(200);

pdf.pipe(res);
pdf.end();
```

This approach works, the PDF downloaded includes the "hello world" text, but this isn't a feasible approach due to performance/memory issues.

```
let chunks = [];    
let pdf = new PDFDocument();

pdf.text("hello world", 50, 50);

pdf.on("data", data => {
  chunks.push(data);
});

pdf.on("end", () => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.setHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    `attachment; filename=test.pdf`
  );
  res.status(200);
  const result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  res.send(
    "data:application/pdf;base64," + result.toString("base64")
  ); 
});

pdf.end();
```

I checked the contents of both PDF files (from both approaches above) and saw that the actual content is different between the two. This was also observed in the raw response logged in Chrome. I won't paste the entire file contents (unless someone thinks that's necessary), but here's where the files differ:

Blank PDF

```
stream
x�e�;
�0�=Ż���g� )-���*����7na'�c��pFǦ<yԛ�_[�d1�>�zӰ1�C�����ͻ��a��} .��d�J,pt�U���*
endstream
```

Working PDF

```
stream
xœeŒ;
€0û=Å»€šÍg£ )-ì„íÄ*ÎÂû7na'ÃcŠÇpFÇ¦<yÔ›â_[ô‹Œd1„>ŒzÓ°1ØC³Œ’¤Í»œØa––±«d³J,pt§Ué ÝÎ*
endstream
```

I don't know much about encoding, so not sure if this is helpful or just gibberish, but it does show there's something different in the encoding between the two files, and maybe I'm not setting something properly in Express.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using a workaround by converting the stream to base64 then decoding it in client.

Express function:

```
const { Base64Encode } = require("base64-stream");

let pdf = new PDFDocument();

pdf.text("hello world", 50, 50);
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
res.setHeader(
  "Content-Disposition",
  `attachment; filename=test.pdf`
);

res.status(200);
pdf.pipe(new Base64Encode()).pipe(res);
pdf.end();
```

Client Code:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
  var binaryString = window.atob(data);
  var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
  for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
    var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    bytes[i] = ascii;
  }
  return bytes;
}

// In my response handler:
const arraybuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(response);
const blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });
saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
```

Comment: Great solution! I was also stuck in same situation and this technique by encoding the string in Base64 worked flawlessly. I am using 'html-pdf' NPM package BTW which was giving me blank PDF file.